# How to dynamic slipt csv file to each file

Tags: c#, csv, datatable

I want to dynammic slipt CSV file to few files.

Example

CSV headear H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7 H8 H9

I select H2 and H4 to create new csv files (H2.csv and H4.csv) with all data belong to this column.

Please show me a good way to do that.

Comment: Are you really waiting someone to write code for you? At least show what have you already tried to do.

Comment: 1. Read header of CSV file to allow user select what header they want to Export to new File
2. I think use datatable to load csv file and loop to export with selected column

Or read csv file again with row by row check each column is selected or not and write to new file.

Answer (score 0):

You should show us what you already did in your code. It will be better of us to help you :)

Here is a try :

```
/// <summary>
/// Get a subtab of a another by specifing the columns index
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tab">a list of lines of your tab</param>
/// <param name="columns">the index of columns you want to keep (the order specified will match the result order of columns)</param>
/// <returns>a list of selected columns</returns>
public List<string[]> SubTab(List<string[]> tab, params int[] columns)
{
    // add error handling here like verifying that specified columns exist in tab

    var result = new List<string[]>();
    foreach (var line in tab)
    {
        var newLine = new string[columns.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.Length; i++)
        {
            newLine[i] = line[columns[i]];
        }
        result.Add(newLine);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks

1. Read header of CSV file to allow user select what header they want to Export to new File 2. I think use datatable to load csv file and loop to export with selected column Or read csv file again with row by row check each column is selected or not and write to new file.